# Struts2: values from action are not seen in jsp, but they are seen in the javascript code from jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, action

In action I have a variable which has getter on it.

```
private String myActionVariable = "predefined....";
public String getMyActionVariable () {
    return myActionVariable;
}
```

In jsp, I try to use my variable in this way:

```
<input type="button" class="styledButton" 
       onclick="javascript: doAjax('myActionName',false);" 
       value="${myActionVariable}"
```

But it is not shown. However, if I output this variable from the javascript code included within the same jsp file:

```
alert (${myActionVariable})
```

I will get the value of it....

Any idea please ? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Standard `<input/>` HTML Tag with an `<s:property />` Struts2 Tag for the value, like this:

```
<input type="button" class="styledButton" 
       onclick="javascript:doAjax('myActionName',false);" 
       value="<s:property value="%{myActionVariable}"/>"/>
```

or a Struts2 Tag directly like this:

```
<s:submit type="button" cssClass="styledButton" 
          onclick="javascript: doAjax('myActionName',false);" 
          value="%{myActionVariable}" />
```

Note that with Struts2 Tag, `class` attribute becomes `cssClass` (and `style` becomes `cssStyle`), and that `%{}` is the right OGNL syntax, instead of `${}` (that is `JSTL` syntax)

---

EDIT: when using Struts2, forget about JSTL, you won't need them anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using struts2 tag.

```
<input type="button" class="styledButton" onclick="javascript: doAjax('myActionName',false);" value="${myActionVariable}">
```

Instead of this, use

```
<s:submit type="button" cssClass="styledButton" onClick="javascript: doAjax('myActionName',false);" value= "myActionVariable" />
```

Comment: You can't use an Struts2 tag from inside another Struts2 tag (`<s:property />` in this case)...